# Combining and duplicating rows based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm searching for an elegant solution for combining, duplicating, and mutating rows based on a condition:

In my example, I would like to combine x = 1 and x = 2 and then duplicate these rows. Then mutate each subset back to their original classification.

**Data**

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6), 
         y = c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), 
         z = c(21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30))
       x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    11    21
 2     1    12    22
 3     1    13    23
 4     2    14    24
 5     2    15    25
 6     2    16    26
 7     3    17    27
 8     4    18    28
 9     5    19    29
10     6    20    30
```

**Current Solution**

Combine rows when x is in 1 or 2 and store them as 1

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(x %in% c(1,2), 1, x))
```

Filter for x is 1 and mutate to 2. Store this as a subset

```
df_temp <- df %>%
  filter(x == 1) %>%
  mutate(x = 2)
```

Bind the rows back

```
df <- rbind(df,df_temp)
```

**Desired Output**

```
       x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    11    21
 2     1    12    22
 3     1    13    23
 4     1    14    24
 5     1    15    25
 6     1    16    26
 7     3    17    27
 8     4    18    28
 9     5    19    29
10     6    20    30
11     2    11    21
12     2    12    22
13     2    13    23
14     2    14    24
15     2    15    25
16     2    16    26
```

I think the first step can be skipped. `separate_rows()` may do the trick here if i combine them with a separator but i'd like to avoid this.

Looking for a dplyr solution.

**EDIT 2:**

If we simplify the data above to:

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6), 
             y = c(11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), 
             z = c(21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,30))
```

Where the number of rows of x = 1 and x = 2 are different. Filtering and reversing y and z no longer gives the correct solution.

**Expected outcome**

```
      x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    11    21
 2     1    12    22
 3     1    14    24
 4     1    15    25
 5     1    16    26
 6     2    14    24
 7     2    15    25
 8     2    16    26
 9     2    11    21
10     2    12    22
11     3    17    27
12     4    18    28
13     5    19    29
14     6    20    30
```

Comment: Can you expand your example and expected output when there are more than 2 rows in the range `1:2` ?

Comment: @RonakShah expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try

```
df %>% 
  full_join(filter(df, x %in% 1:2) %>% complete(x, y)) 
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     3     8
4     1     7
5     2     6
```

When including column `z`, one has to complete over the nested columns `y` & `z` like

```
df %>% 
  full_join(filter(df, x %in% 1:2) %>% 
              complete(x, nesting(y, z))) %>% 
  arrange(x)
# A tibble: 16 x 3
       x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    11    21
 2     1    12    22
 3     1    13    23
 4     1    14    24
 5     1    15    25
 6     1    16    26
 7     2    14    24
 8     2    15    25
 9     2    16    26
10     2    11    21
11     2    12    22
12     2    13    23
13     3    17    27
14     4    18    28
15     5    19    29
16     6    20    30
```

Comment: Thanks. This works when we have two columns. I've added another column `z` to my example with an expected output. Much appreciated if you can have another look

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` the rows where `x` is either 1 or 2, reverse `y` and `z` columns and bind the data back to the original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(x %in% 1:2) %>%
  mutate(across(y:z, rev)) %>%
  #In old dplyr use mutate_at
  #mutate_at(vars(y:z), rev) %>%
  bind_rows(df)


# A tibble: 16 x 3
#       x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    16    26
# 2     1    15    25
# 3     1    14    24
# 4     2    13    23
# 5     2    12    22
# 6     2    11    21
# 7     1    11    21
# 8     1    12    22
# 9     1    13    23
#10     2    14    24
#11     2    15    25
#12     2    16    26
#13     3    17    27
#14     4    18    28
#15     5    19    29
#16     6    20    30
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is probably not a good example again as `x = 1` and `x = 2` both have the same number of rows (3). If they do not, let's say remove row 3, we end up with 4 rows for `x =1` and 6 rows for `x = 2`. The end result should have the same number of rows. I can change my example again.